# How to find the equation of the line tangent to a curve in a given point

Tags: geometry, derivatives, curves, tangent-line

Let $f$ be:

$$f(x) = 100 - x^2 $$

As far as I understand, the slope of the line tangent to such curve is given by its derivative:

$$ f'(x) = -2x $$

I want the equation of the line tangent to $f$ at the point it crosses the x-axis, so  $10$ if I'm not mistaken.

How can I infer this equation?

Note: I'm working with this function in Sage: [sage online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gtkw.png)

## EDIT

With the comments and this:

https://mathsathome.com/equation-of-a-tangent/

I managed to get what I wanted.

Here is the Sage code I used:

```
f(x) = 100 - x**2
fd(x) = -2*x

# The following comes from solving y = mx + c for c, 
# knowing that my point of interest is x = 10 
# (because that's were f cuts the x-axis), 
# so y = f(10) = 0, so m = fd(10). 
fr(x) = fd(10)*x + 200

p1 = plot(f, (0, 10))
p2 = plot(fr, (0, 10), color='green')

p1 + p2
```

Here the plot:

[image]

And here a link to the test:

https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJw9zDsKgDAQhOE-kDtMZzYP2GzvadTYBBOCRY7vgmL5fzBT3CSsyMxImN6LNWV_LYmfWuMt1czkJwKE2Rprelbutd2uRDiOekKkLD-P3yO2VttYl3Mcx7XQtw_o8gBu7x3Y&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==

Comment: The equation of a line with slope $k$ and containing the point $(a,b)$ is $y-b=k(x-a).$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you find the equation of a tangent line to an equation: $\sin$ in it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1486383/how-do-you-find-the-equation-of-a-tangent-line-to-an-equation-sin-in-it) If not, look for other posts [in this list](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=equation+of+the+tangent), similar to your (mega)duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for the comments; I have what I wanted. @AnneBauval that's kind of more complex than what I wanted, so I will publish what I did as an answer.

Comment: Don't publish it as an answer. Instead, edit your post to improve its quality. Please read [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) and [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Comment: @AnneBauval then shall I leave this question unanswered and close it?

Comment: Since your initial post was a (nearly) "no-effort question", I only gave you a hint as first comment (similar to the answer in the linked post), instead of the full solution, which, applied to $k=-20$ and $(a,b)=(10,0)$, is simply$$y=-20(x-10).$$ It is more direct than puting $y=mx+c$ and "solving for $c$".

Comment: I think this question should be left unanswered, and closed as a duplicate of [many similar ones](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=equation+of+the+tangent), such as [this one, already linked in my 2nd comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1486402)

Comment: To investigate $y−(100−x^2)=0$ around $(x,y)=(10,0),$ translate $y−(100−(x+10)^2)=y+x^2+20x=0,$ i.e. the original equation can be written $y+(x−10)^2+20(x−10)=0.$ Now drop the quadratic term to get the equation of the tangent line $y+20(x-10)=0.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the general formula of a tangent line on the function $f$ in the point $(x_0, y_0)$:

$$y=(x-x_0) \cdot f'(x_0) + y_0$$

Obviously: $y_0 = f(x_0)$

In your case:

$$y = (x - 10) \cdot (-2 \cdot 10) + 0 = -20x + 200$$